# Trying to pass extracted text from Tesseract OCR to custom google search

Tags: python, ocr

Having some trouble with a project and hopefully someone can help! I'm trying to take extracted text from tesseract OCR and use that text as the search query of Google Chrome searches. My shell script can extract the text and launch Chrome, but I cant figure out how to send the text to the searchbar of chrome. Below are some pictures of my script. I'm extremely new to coding, so any help is appreciated.

Shell script

```
echo "Realtime Screen OCR"
while true 
do
echo "Waiting for trigger"
read
screencapture -R31,205,420,420 screens.png
tesseract screens.png ocr
OCR=`cat ocr.txt`
python3 launch1.py $OCR
##/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome $OCR
echo "Opened Chrome...waiting for next question"
done
```

Python Script

```
import urllib.parse
search_query = input("enter search query")
query_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(search_query)
google_search_url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + 
format(query_encoded)
import webbrowser 
webbrowser.open(google_search_url)
```

Comment: What exactly is the challenge you're trying to overcome?  Accessing the argument that is passed into the python script?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the only step you're missing is grabbing the text in your Python code and passing it into the search query.  You can do this using `sys.`  In this example we replace the user-inputted text with retrieving the argument from the command line, assuming that this is what you're trying to do.

```
import urllib.parse
import sys
search_query = sys.argv[1]
query_encoded = urllib.parse.quote_plus(search_query)
google_search_url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + 
format(query_encoded)
import webbrowser 
webbrowser.open(google_search_url)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That definitely fixed my problem. However, it appears that only the first word of the extracted text ends up being searched in google. For example, if the phrase thats captured is "What size pizza do you want?", it will only search for "What". Any idea how to fix this? It doesn't appear to be tesseract because I can see the .txt files and they look fine.

Comment: @HunterRios In your shell script, try putting $OCR in quotation marks when you launch the python script.  See if this works: python3 launch1.py "$OCR"